# iPad Game: is Objective-C too slow (vs. plain C)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, c

I was beginning to design a new game for the iPad and I came a cross an article that said I should write the game in C rather than objective-c because objective-c is just too slow.

Can anyone comment on this? I dont know C or C++ but i am trying to find the best way to develop this game.

Thanks!

Comment: Write in it assembly because C is too slow.

Comment: You can write the critical parts of your program in C, and the rest in Objective C.

Comment: Your own code is going to cause framerate drops **long** before the obj-c runtime will.

Comment: By the way, if you don't know C, how do you want to develop in Objective-C? Objective-C is 90% C and 10% OO layer...

Comment: Well I just learned objective-c so i suppose i know some C but i have never tried it

Comment: If you know Objective-C, then you know C also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't be afraid about Objective-C's speed. Its runtime is higly optimized by Apple's engineers, and don't forget that recent iDevices have a very good and fast hardware.

The major reason against plain C is that you won't find a good/easy-to-use game development library for C, as all of iOS' graphics and other media processing libraries are written in Objctive-C.

Comment: Why the hell are you downvoting this?

Comment: Well lets say that i wanted to have 20+ sprites on the screen at a single time and they would all be doing their own thing? Also would C++ be an option? or again would i not see that much of a boost?

Comment: I suppose what has me a little freaked out is this article http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/22/why-game-devs-dont-use-objective-c/

Comment: @JamesDunay so you downvoted because of this article? Btw *no need* to post this link under all of the answers...

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to ask youself a some questions; the answers will help determine what course you'll want to take. Here are two I feel are very important:

1. What kind of game? Where will performance make a difference in the user's experience as she/he plays?
2. What are your current skills? How much do you need to learn? (As you said that you don't know C, you'll need to at least learn C. How difficult that is will depend on your experience and the number of languages in which you are currently fluent. And of course implementing in Objective-C implies at least a moderate depth of understanding of C.)
3. What kind(s) of capabilities will the game need? (E.g,. 3-D with collision detection? Word lookup in a dictionary?) How will you provide these? What existing software can you leverage to meet such needs?

If you feel there will be an area where performance is important, it would make sense to mock up a basic approach and get a feel for what kind of performance your approach has. The best way to improve performance in a large amount is to come up with a better approach / algorithm. It's much harder to get a big performance gain out of an existing approach by profiling and tweaking.

The easiest most 'native' development approach for iOS is of course to use Objective-C. That's what the great majority of apps are written in, and that is where you'll find the best tools and techniques. Plus most of the support libraries you will probably want to use will be for Objective-C.

Hope that gives you some useful direction.

Comment: I suppose what has me a little freaked out is this article http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/22/why-game-devs-dont-use-objective-c/

Comment: Hence my comments regarding the type of game and prototyping to investigate performance. His comments are very relevant for a 'processor intensive' game, as he notes.